# How to save rails_admin record to mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, action, rails-admin

I am struggling with understanding how to save a model to MongoDB using mongoid and rails_admin.

I've got my model:

```
class PictureAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :data_file_name, type: String
  field :data_content_type, type: String
  field :data_file_size, type: Integer
end
```

This was made through a generation:

```
bundle exec rails g model PictureAsset data_file_name:string data_content_type:string data_file_size:integer
```

Rails admin side loads up just fine, and I can navigate to the index page for PictureAsset.

When I try to access my custom action, `asset_action`, I get the following error:

`` undefined method `belongs_to' for #<RailsAdmin::AbstractModel:0xbf2e791> ``

My action looks like this:

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class AssetAction < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :collection do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get, :put]
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            if request.get? # EDIT
              binding.pry
              respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render @action.template_name }
                format.js   { render @action.template_name, layout: false }
              end

            elsif request.put? # UPDATE
              binding.pry
              #newUserPropVal.save
            end
          end
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-list-alt'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your model includes code for both ActiveRecord and Mongoid. Pick one and remove code for the other.

ActiveRecord will look like this:

```
class PictureAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
  # No field definitions needed
end
```

Mongoid will look like this:

```
# Does not derive from anything
class PictureAsset
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :data_file_name, type: String
  field :data_content_type, type: String
  field :data_file_size, type: Integer
end
```

This may not solve the error you are getting but is a good start.